# Unit vectors with imaginary numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I'm trying to determine if the matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & i \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
is a unitary matrix.

Therefore, the first step I'm taking is to figure out if both $\langle 0, 1\rangle$ and $\langle i, 0\rangle$ are unit vectors.  $\langle 0, 1\rangle$ is obviously a unit vector, however, I'm not sure exactly what the rule is when it comes to determining if a vector is a unit vector when you have imaginary numbers in it, because at least in this case, the magnitude is not $1$, it is:
$$
\mathrm{mag}(\langle i, 0\rangle) = i
$$
(which is the sqrt of $-1$) and not $1$.  So even though the magnitude is imaginary. Is it still considered a unit vector?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a unitary matrix, because $A^HA$ is the identity, where $A^H$ denotes the hermitian transpose:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & i \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
A^HA=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-i & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & i \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Specifically to address your last question:
The magnitude of a vector $(v_1, v_2, ..., v_n)$ is given by $$\sqrt{|v_1|^2 + |v_2|^2 + ... + |v_n|^2}.$$ When working in $\Bbb R^n$, the absolute values are superfluous, so we tend to omit them. But in $\Bbb C^n$, they are required. So the magnitude of $(i, 0)$ is $1$, not $i$.

Magnitude (aka *norm*) needs to be a real number to be fully useful, as it most commonly used in inequalities and inequalities are not defined on the complex numbers. Thus we define it in $\Bbb C^n$ as I've shown.